# boquear diretórios e arquivos com .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Não tenho muito conhecimento em `.htaccess` e me deparei com um projeto em que o mesmo bloqueava algumas imagens que eu subia para uma pasta img do projeto.

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/(.*)$ statics/$1/$2 [L]
```

Porém outras imagens desta pasta carregavam normalmente. O estranho é que pesquisei pelo nome das imagens que carregavam dentro do arquivo `.htaccess` e não encontrei. Então não sei como ele bloqueava algumas e outras não.

Mas ao remover `img` da regra todas as imagens passaram a carregar.

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/(.*)$ statics/$1/$2 [L]
```

As minhas dúvidas são:

- Porque bloquear o carregamento das imagens em um projeto?
- Removendo `img` da regra, estou expondo a segurança da minha aplicação de alguma forma?

Comment: Isto não esta bloqueando carregar nada, isto esta redirecionando pastas css, js e img para uma pasta "virtual" (uma rota) que fique assim `http://site/statics/img/image.jpg`

Comment: Olá Guilherme, perfeita a sua analise. É exatamente isso. procurei e localizei a pasta statics no projeto e la dentro existe outra pasta img para onde esse redirecionamento está indo. Muito obrigado por esclarecer!

Answer (score 1):

Depende do por quê disso, se você não quer o vazamento da foto de alguma pessoa pode ser útil.

Remover a segurança(img) não estaria removendo a segurança(da aplicação), ao meu ver, só removeria a privacidade.

se você quer fazer com que só algumas imagens sejam públicas, seguindo o mesmo raciocínio você pode fazer algo do tipo

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js|img)/((?!private_).*)$ statics/$1/$2 [L]
```

VOcê pode ver isso funcionando aqui https://regex101.com/r/bPBN1Q/2
Só tirar o **private_** que o regex "corresponde"